# OpenCV traincascade maxWeekCount

Tags: opencv, cascade, object-detection

I am training a LBP detector with OpenCV, does anyone knows how does the maxWeakCount influence the detector? Does it make it slower or does it make it not so good in detecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

max weak count is the maximum amount of weak trees that the detector will follow before it moves on.

Therefore the lower this number the more likely that your system is going to stop classifying before it has reached the maxFalseAlarmRate. - You want it bigger

Try setting it to 100 see how you get on

Also, see [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html)

"-maxWeakCount max_weak_tree_count

Maximal count of weak trees for every cascade stage. The boosted classifier (stage) will have so many weak trees (<=maxWeakCount), as needed to achieve the given -maxFalseAlarmRate."

Comment: Ok, Thanks, then this means, supposing one stage, if it has 35 weakCounts it is slower than the one with 10 (I think I have mistaken in the question: weakCount instead of maxWeakCount)

Comment: I think you may mean maxDepth? the amount of questions it has to answer with true before it fails?

However, I think the answer to your question is yes, although it is a little unclear.

(Feel free to mark an accepted answer)